# Valid certificate issued by certificate authority

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate

Using the below configuration:
internal Domain: company.corp
Server 2008 DC and CA

I've setup Radius/NPS for WPA2-Enterprise authentication, but the mobile clients are getting certificate warnings because the PEAP certificate is self signed by the CA.

How can I fix the warning? Do I need to get a signed certificate for the company.corp domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either need to get a certificate signed by one of the trusted CA's or add your CA's certificated as a trusted root on your mobile clients. The process on how to do this will differ by client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Fyi, I've tried this and trusting certificates on Android is not trivial. It works on iPhone, Blackberry and Windows Mobile fine though.

Comment: My question is do I have to obtain a certificate for *.company.corp? And if so what process do I have to follow to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Null: no you shouldn't need a wildcard certificate (unless you have other uses for it) Just a certificate for the host that they will be connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to get a PEAP certificate signed by a CA that can be traversed from the mobile device's [root certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificates)s.